# ByteArrayOutputStream is not set properly

Tags: java, bufferedimage, bytearrayinputstream

```
MultipartFile mpf = null;
final BufferedImage resizedImage = imageResizeService.resize(requestResizeReq);
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ImageIO.write( resizedImage,mpf.getContentType() , baos );
         profilePictureService.saveProfilePicture(account.getId(),baos.toByteArray());
```

`resizedImage` is

```
BufferedImage@1f79b067: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@65da4a76 transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 200 height = 500 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 701
```

`baos`  is empty. Any idea?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hot link to a small (in bytes) image that has the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem with content type. It was image/jpeg so the new code looks like follows.

```
 ImageIO.write( resizedImage,mpf.getContentType().replace("image/", "") , baos );
```